# Cortex-M DWT cycle counter inconsistent measurement

Tags: embedded, arm, measurement, timer

I recently [discovered](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/01/30/cycle-counting-on-arm-cortex-m-with-dwt/) that it's possible to use a free running counter embedded in most Cortex-M4 cores to measure the performance of a chunk of code.
I'm trying it on my LPC4370, where I want to measure how much time does it take to move a pin un and down.
My code is this:

```
/*SET UP GPIO debug*/
/* use with LPC_GPIO_PORT->B[DEBUGPIN_PORT][DEBUG_PIN0] = TRUE; */
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, DEBUGPIN_PORT, DEBUG_PIN0);
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, DEBUGPIN_PORT, DEBUG_PIN1);
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, DEBUGPIN_PORT, DEBUG_PIN2);
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, DEBUGPIN_PORT, DEBUG_PIN3);
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, DEBUGPIN_PORT, DEBUG_PIN4);

/*DEBUG Timer Init*/

uint32_t delta;
uint32_t max = 0;
uint32_t min = 0xFFFFFFFF;

LPC4370_InitCycleCounter(); /*Init DWT HW*/

while(1)
{
    LPC4370_ResetCycleCounter(); /* reset cycle counter */

    LPC4370_EnableCycleCounter(); /* start counting */
    LPC_GPIO_PORT->B[DEBUGPIN_PORT][DEBUG_PIN1] = TRUE;
    LPC_GPIO_PORT->B[DEBUGPIN_PORT][DEBUG_PIN1] = FALSE;

    delta = LPC4370_GetCycleCounter();

    if(delta < min)
    {
        min = delta;
    }

    if (max < delta)
    {
        max = delta;
    }
}
```

And the needed defines for the timer:

```
/* DWT (Data Watchpoint and Trace) registers, only exists on ARM Cortex with a DWT unit */

#define LPC4370_DWT_CONTROL   (*((volatile uint32_t*)0xE0001000))
/*!< DWT Control register */
#define LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNTENA_BIT (1UL<<0)
/*!< CYCCNTENA bit in DWT_CONTROL register */
#define LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNT        (*((volatile uint32_t*)0xE0001004))
/*!< DWT Cycle Counter register */ 
#define LPC4370_DEMCR             (*((volatile uint32_t*)0xE000EDFC))
/*!< DEMCR: Debug Exception and Monitor Control Register */
#define LPC4370_TRCENA_BIT              (1UL<<24)
/*!< Trace enable bit in DEMCR register */

#define LPC4370_InitCycleCounter() \
LPC4370_DEMCR |= LPC4370_TRCENA_BIT
 /*!< TRCENA: Enable trace and debug block DEMCR (Debug Exception and Monitor Control Register */

#define LPC4370_ResetCycleCounter() \
LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNT = 0
/*!< Reset cycle counter */

#define LPC4370_EnableCycleCounter() \
LPC4370_DWT_CONTROL |= LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNTENA_BIT
/*!< Enable cycle counter */

#define LPC4370_DisableCycleCounter() \
LPC4370_DWT_CONTROL &= ~LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNTENA_BIT
/*!< Disable cycle counter */

#define LPC4370_GetCycleCounter() \
LPC4370_DWT_CYCCNT
/*!< Read cycle counter register */
```

To compute the elepased time I do cycles_number*(1/f_clk): in this case f_clk = 204 MHz.

After a few try what I got is this:

- min = 22 cycles (~100ns)
- max = 2450 cycles (~12us)

Where this high value of max happens at the first iteration.
Here's a picture of what I see on the scope (which I believe agrees with the min measurement):
[image]

Putting the scope in single mode (DC coupling) I'm able to capture the first pulse:
[image]

From this I notice 2 things:

- pulse length is 6us instead of the expected 12us (as measured with DWT)
- smaller pulses do not have the time to range from 0 to 3V while this one does.

So, any idea why do I get this outlier?

Comment: you would have to look at the datasheet, very possible that there is a cache of some sort in front of flash, so the first time through your loop it was not cached then remaining times it was.  Not necessarily a cache in the cortex-m some mcus have a documented or undocumented cache in front of the flash that you may or may not have control over.  Likewise a branch predictor, that needs one time through the loop to remember (cache) that there is a branch at that address.

Comment: If you think it is first time through then you should be able to craft an experiment to show that on the scope between the first gpio state change and the second compared to second and third.  put some nops in the loop.

Comment: you can probably use the system timer and not need library code (forget what DWT access looks like), should still have the same kind of effect but the difference will get smaller.

Comment: alignment of the code in memory can affect both numbers.   running this code from ram instead of flash should improve the performance of the code, but you are also bound by the speed of the peripheral to respond to the access and eventually that may determine the performance.

Comment: Thank you @old_timer for the comments. Do you think that moving the code in RAM would avoid the cache issue that you mentioned? I guess this could still happen with cache of the M4

Comment: Not sure it would explain your issue but remember to disable interrupts

Comment: assume each brand and family of microcontroller is different even if they all share the same arm core.  You really need to just try it.  (Michael Abrash Zen of assembly language) And be careful of your assumptions over what is going on, test your theories on what changed the performance and leave a little room for doubt in your theory.  Sometimes try crazy things that shouldnt help or should make it worse to see what that does.

Comment: I forget if the m4 has a cache, and not all of the cores with a cache are enabled in the chip, up to the chip vendor in some cases.  if it is cached then that should outperform ram or match it.  but the first time through (the while(1) loop) will be slower than the others.  you have this timing code in the loop so that first to second pulse delta is longer, once you remove that the delta will change.  if you do this without while loops for your real application you just have to deal with this time delta if you bit bang

Comment: if you cant tolerate this then you should use the timers and timer outputs to create pulses.  (or other peripherals depending on what you are doing)

Comment: AC characteristics for generic MCU pins is typically something roughly around 20ns to 200ns toggle time. Start by checking that up in the datasheet and take it from there.